# How do i send api post to local even after change ip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost, local-network

I usually send a POST request from mobile WIFI network to my local server `https://192.168.0.23:8000` (gateway is `192.168.0.1`) (both are connected to the same network)

Now if i change the gateway IP say from `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.1.1`
Sending a POST request to `192.168.0.23:8000` obviously won't work, I need to manually change the POST request to `192.168.1.23:8000`

Is there a more efficient way of doing these things? **without using the public network**. I just want to use local network.

Comment: I don't think so. Just change the port in your request.

Comment: Maybe you can name the .23 machine with your router config, and access it via `https://myserver:8000`